# Most groups are noncommutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

From page 41 of [Evan Chen's napkin](https://venhance.github.io/napkin/Napkin.pdf) it states that most groups are noncommutative. This led me to think about an unconventional question: let
$$C_n:=\text{number of nonisomorphic abelian groups of order }n$$
$$G_n:=\text{number of nonisomorphic groups of order }n.$$
Are there any known results on $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{C_n}{G_n}$ or $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{C_n}{G_n}$? Notice from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups#Classifying_groups_of_small_order), for $p$ prime we have $C_{p^3}/G_{p^3}=3/5$, so we can deduce
$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{C_n}{G_n}\leq\frac{3}{5}$$
and also since $C_{p^2}/G_{p^2}=1$, we have
$$1\leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{C_n}{G_n}.$$
My question is, can these bounds be improved, and is determining the exact value possible?

Edit: I realize that since $C_n/G_n\leq 1$ for all $n$, we obviously have $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}C_n/G_n=1$. So forget about that.

Comment: Since the limsup can't be $>1$ you can change the second "$\le$" to just "$=$" - also, it's easier to consider $p$ rather than $p^2$ there, but that's a side point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n=2^k$, $k\gg 1$, [then](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30358/number-of-non-abelian-groups-of-order-2n) $C_n\ll G_n$, so the $\liminf=0$.

Comment: What result are you using to argue $C_n\ll G_n$?

Comment: See this MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30358/number-of-non-abelian-groups-of-order-2n

Comment: To make this precise: there are $2^{\frac{2}{27}n^3+O(n^{8/3})}$ groups of order $2^n$, and there are only $p(n) \sim \frac{1}{4n\sqrt{3}} e^{\pi \sqrt{2n/3}}$ abelian groups of order $2^n$. From this you can easily show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} C_{2^n}/G_{2^n} = 0$.

Comment: Right. The first estimate is in the first (highest upvoted) answer to the question in my link. The second follows because every abelian group is a direct product of cyclic groups (so $p(n)$ is the partition function),

Comment: Thanks all. The length of the answer made me think that $C_n\ll G_n$ is obvious, but turns out that there are deeper results involved.

Comment: It is not obvious. It is just "well known to specialists". "Almost all finite groups are non-Abelian 2-groups" - is what most people dealing with finite groups believe is true.

Comment: Proving the lower bound on the number of groups of order $2^n$ (a result of Graham Higman) is not exactly routine, but it is not seriously difficult, and it is worthwhile and instructive  to try and read and understand the proof. The bound is derived by considering 2-groups $G$ in which $G$ and $G/Z(G)$ are both elementary abelian.